# Fbx 3d model moving from its place in real world even when it is spawned using marker

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-maps-markers, augmented-reality

I am developing a project in which an fbx 3d model is spawned and placed in the real world using a marker. But after moving my device, the model starts moving slowly too. I'm using an Android device.

Is it due to the absence of a LiDAR scanner that is present in iOS mobile devices or do I have to write some code or work on the settings for it?

I have not tried any iOS device, so I have no idea and wanted to make sure before investing in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is enough as I have not got any answer here but these are the few things I have worked and was little satisfied with the output.

1. First, for my project LIDAR was important as the model was huge, so I am currently using iOS devices. For small model, LiDAR is not that important.
2. The image marker should be clear, and since I am using Vuforia, the feature points was less, so image of the image marker should consist more distinct features.
3. Try to place the image marker in a straight horizontal or vertical plane, for better detection.

These few things helped me with better result. If there are more, please add. It will be helpful for me and the others.